# ODOO-v8 :How to view the homepage alone without logged in?

Tags: python, web, odoo-8, odoo, qweb

I'm trying to create a page where anyone can see the homepage without login, Any idea?

Comment: By default it works like that, when you log in as a user@Jesus

Comment: Check my answer@Jesus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Remove all the accesses for the public users in settings but check PORTAL USER box under Other Extra Rights. So when a user views the homepage, there won't be any login. Users can view the homepage without logged in.